# check OS and processor is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Tags: vb6, wmi

I want vb6 code to check OS is 32 bit or 64 bit and also processor is 32 bit or 64 bit.So please help me to get these codes.
In vb.net i can use Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem Property and it works only in .net 4.0 and above.
But how can i get these information in vb6?

Comment: For bitness try this: http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_get_os_name.html

Answer (score 3):

For CPU you can use WMI and get AddressWidth.
A sample of VBScript can be found [here](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/computermanagement/hardware/)

Comment: You can query the OSArchitecture property of the Win32_OperatingSystem class. [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/library/aa394239.aspx)

Comment: That's not correct. `AddressWidth` is 32 if you're running 32-bit OS on 64-bit processor, actually. I dim my answer is correct http://stackoverflow.com/a/15860411/262403.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way to answer both questions seems to be using [Win32_Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class.

---

#### Is operating system 32-bit or 64-bit?

For operating system one can check `AddressWidth` property:

> **AddressWidth**
>
> On a 32-bit operating system, the value is 32 and on a 64-bit
>   operating system it is 64.

Relevant VB6 code is:

```
Public Function GetOsBitness() As String
    Dim ProcessorSet As Object
    Dim CPU As Object

    Set ProcessorSet = GetObject("Winmgmts:"). _
        ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")
    For Each CPU In ProcessorSet
        GetOsBitness = CStr(CPU.AddressWidth)
    Next
End Function
```

---

#### Is processor 32-bit or 64-bit?

For processor one can check `DataWidth` property:

> **DataWidth**
>
> On a 32-bit processor, the value is 32 and on a 64-bit processor it is
>   64.

Relevant VB6 code is:

```
Public Function GetCpuBitness() As String
    Dim ProcessorSet As Object
    Dim CPU As Object

    Set ProcessorSet = GetObject("Winmgmts:"). _
        ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")
    For Each CPU In ProcessorSet
        GetCpuBitness = CStr(CPU.DataWidth)
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `DataWidth` or `AddressWidth` properties of the [`Win32_Processor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class, On a 32-bit processor, the value is 32 and on a 64-bit processor it is 64.

Answer (score 1):

**Operating system architecture**

One way to obtain it is to use `GetNativeSystemInfo` WinAPI function. It is covered in [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811006/checking-processor-is-32-bit-or-64-bit).

OS architecture can be obtained through WMI too, in case you'd like to achieve both goals in similar way. In Windows Vista and newer operating systems one can query `Win32_OperatingSystem` class and analyze `OSArchitecture` property ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/library/aa394239.aspx)). Sadly, this property doesn't exist in Windows XP and earlier versions. On these systems one may query `Win32_ComputerSystem` class and analyze `SystemType` property instead ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

```
Public Function GetOsArchitecture()
    If IsAtLeastVista Then
        GetOsArchitecture = GetVistaOsArchitecture
    Else
        GetOsArchitecture = GetXpOsArchitecture
    End If
End Function

Private Function IsAtLeastVista() As Boolean
    IsAtLeastVista = GetOsVersion >= "6.0"
End Function

Private Function GetOsVersion() As String
    Dim OperatingSystemSet As Object
    Dim OS As Object

    Set OperatingSystemSet = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}"). _
                                    InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem")
    For Each OS In OperatingSystemSet
        GetOsVersion = Left$(Trim$(OS.Version), 3)
    Next
End Function

Private Function GetVistaOsArchitecture() As String
    Dim OperatingSystemSet As Object
    Dim OS As Object

    Set OperatingSystemSet = GetObject("Winmgmts:"). _
        ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")
    For Each OS In OperatingSystemSet
        GetVistaOsArchitecture = Left$(Trim$(OS.OSArchitecture), 2)
    Next
End Function

Private Function GetXpOsArchitecture() As String
    Dim ComputerSystemSet As Object
    Dim Computer As Object
    Dim SystemType As String

    Set ComputerSystemSet = GetObject("Winmgmts:"). _
        ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")
    For Each Computer In ComputerSystemSet
        SystemType = UCase$(Left$(Trim$(Computer.SystemType), 3))
    Next

    GetXpOsArchitecture = IIf(SystemType = "X86", "32", "64")
End Function
```

Comment: Address width does not specify whether process is 32 bit or 64 bit according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx Instead 'Architecture' in Win32_Processor  tells the Processor architecture.

Comment: @winman I made more tests, and you're correct. I dropped CPU-related part from this post (as it was wrong indeed), and posted different answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15860411/262403

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows Xp 32b, the Win32_Processor.AddressWidth returns ALWAYS 32. See the post [How does the MAP tool find out it's a 64-Bit machine?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/105ced89-d858-4aa9-9491-ec2e0f7dfdb6/how-does-the-map-tool-find-out-its-a-64bit-machine)